# Tensorflow Model on GCP - Converting JSON Prediction request to correct model input

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, google-cloud-platform

I have trained a model using the Wild ML implementation of a CNN which can be found [here](https://github.com/dennybritz/cnn-text-classification-tf), and deployed it to Google Cloud Platform.  I am now trying to send a JSON prediction request to the model, but I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/XXX/PycharmProjects/CNN-Prediction/prediction.py", line 73, in <module>
    print(predict_json(project, model, [json_request], version="TestV2"))
  File "C:/Users/XXX/PycharmProjects/CNN-Prediction/prediction.py", line 63, in predict_json
    raise RuntimeError(response['error'])
RuntimeError: Prediction failed: Error during model execution: AbortionError(code=StatusCode.INVALID_ARGUMENT, details="Shape [-1,11] has negative dimensions
     [[Node: input_y = Placeholder[_output_shapes=[[-1,11]], dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[?,11], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]")
```

I am finding it a challenge to interpret this error, but my impression is it could be because I am sending in JSON data into my model but the model takes in an array of integers which can be seen in the TextCNN class below.

***Question:  How and where in the code do I implement a modification which allows me to convert a JSON input request into a format which the model can then operate on?***

```
  class TextCNN(object):
"""
A CNN for text classification.
Uses an embedding layer, followed by a convolutional, max-pooling and softmax layer.
"""

#  Constructor - sequence length = no. grams in complaint, num_classes = no. categories, vocab_size, embedding_size = dimensions of embedding
def __init__(
        self, sequence_length, num_classes, vocab_size,
        embedding_size, filter_sizes, num_filters, l2_reg_lambda=0.0):
    # Placeholders for input, output and dropout
    self.input_x = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, sequence_length],
                                  name="input_x")  # NN interface to take in complaints
    self.input_y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, num_classes],
                                  name="input_y")  # NN interface to take in complaint labels
    self.dropout_keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name="dropout_keep_prob")

    # Keeping track of l2 regularization loss (optional)
    l2_loss = tf.constant(0.0)

    # Embedding layer - maps vocab word indices into low-dimensional vector representations (basically LU table)
    # name_scope - adds all operations into top-level node called 'embedding' - nice hierarchy when visualising in TB
    # Embedding layer
    with tf.device('/cpu:0'), tf.name_scope("embedding"):
        self.W = tf.Variable(
            tf.random_uniform([vocab_size, embedding_size], -1.0, 1.0), trainable=False,
            name="W")
        self.embedded_chars = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(self.W,
                                                     self.input_x)  # uses weight matrix to map word indices in complaints
        self.embedded_chars_expanded = tf.expand_dims(self.embedded_chars,
                                                      -1)  # expand dimensions of tensor so that we can use conv2d

    # Create a convolution + maxpool layer for each filter size
    # Since we have different size filters each convolution produces tensors of different shapes, so we need to iterate through them,
    pooled_outputs = []
    for i, filter_size in enumerate(filter_sizes):
        with tf.name_scope("conv-maxpool-%s" % filter_size):
            # Convolution Layerc
            filter_shape = [filter_size, embedding_size, 1, num_filters]
            W = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(filter_shape, stddev=0.1), name="W")
            b = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[num_filters]), name="b")
            conv = tf.nn.conv2d(
                self.embedded_chars_expanded,
                W,
                strides=[1, 1, 1, 1],
                padding="VALID",
                name="conv")
            # Apply nonlinearity
            h = tf.nn.relu(tf.nn.bias_add(conv, b), name="relu")
            # Maxpooling over the outputs
            pooled = tf.nn.max_pool(
                h,
                ksize=[1, sequence_length - filter_size + 1, 1, 1],
                strides=[1, 1, 1, 1],
                padding='VALID',
                name="pool")
            pooled_outputs.append(pooled)

    # Combine all the pooled features
    num_filters_total = num_filters * len(filter_sizes)
    print(pooled_outputs)
    self.h_pool = tf.concat(pooled_outputs, axis=3)
    self.h_pool_flat = tf.reshape(self.h_pool, [-1, num_filters_total])

    # Add dropout
    with tf.name_scope("dropout"):
        self.h_drop = tf.nn.dropout(self.h_pool_flat, self.dropout_keep_prob)

    # Final (unnormalized) scores and predictions
    with tf.name_scope("output"):
        W = tf.get_variable(
            "W",
            shape=[num_filters_total, num_classes],
            initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())
        b = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[num_classes]), name="b")
        l2_loss += tf.nn.l2_loss(W)
        l2_loss += tf.nn.l2_loss(b)
        self.scores = tf.nn.xw_plus_b(self.h_drop, W, b, name="scores")
        self.predictions = tf.argmax(self.scores, 1, name="predictions")

    # CalculateMean cross-entropy loss
    with tf.name_scope("loss"):
        print(self.scores)
        print(self.input_y)
        losses = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=self.scores, labels=self.input_y)
        self.loss = tf.reduce_mean(losses) + l2_reg_lambda * l2_loss

    # Accuracy
    with tf.name_scope("accuracy"):
        correct_predictions = tf.equal(self.predictions, tf.argmax(self.input_y, 1))
        self.accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_predictions, "float"), name="accuracy")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue does have nothing to do with the `train.py` and `text_cnn.py`. They build your model. After building your model, do the following modifications in your `eval.py` code.

First, you can use argument library to get your JSON file.

```
import argparse
parser  = argparser.ArgumentParser()

# Input Arguments
parser.add_argument(
      '--eval-file',
      help='local paths to evaluation data',
      nargs='+',
      required=True
  )
args = parser.parse_args()
```

Then you can execute your code as below:

`python eval.py --eval-file YourJSONFile`

Then use,

```
import json
json.loads(Data)
```

to get your data from the `args` or use dict library to
convert your data into the following  array format:

```
x_raw = ["key", "Value"] 
x_test = np.array(list(vocab_processor.transform(x_raw)))
```

After converting your data to  `x_raw`, the code above transforms your data to the appropriate format for TensorFlow.